# How to extract date AND hour from date time in python?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

What's the best way to do this? I thought about extracting the two separately then combining them? This doesn't seem like it should be the most efficient way?

```
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.date
df['hour'] = df['datetime'].hour

df['dateAndHour'] = df['datetime'].dt.date.astype(str) + ' ' + df['datetime'].dt.hour.astype(str)
```

Comment: If you need 2 columns this is the way. other option is converting dattime to `MM-hh` format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strftime` and it depends on the format your date is in and how you want to combine them

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':[datetime.now()]})
df['date-hour'] = df.date.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H')
df
                      date        date-hour
0   2020-11-18 11:03:38.390393  2020-11-18 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to do with it, but one way to do this would be to use `strftime` to format the datetime column to `%Y-%m-%d %H` or similar:

```
>>> df
             datetime
0 2020-01-01 12:15:00
1 2020-10-22 11:11:11

>>> df.datetime.dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H")                                                            
0    2020-01-01 12
1    2020-10-22 11
Name: datetime, dtype: object
```